# Help with nested AND/OR for Process Builder criteria node

Tags: formula, process-builder, criteria

Keen for some help with this formula please.

It's ignoring the PRIORVALUE OR statement so presumably the order of what I'm doing is incorrect even though PB accepts this syntax:

```
AND ( 
ISCHANGED([Opportunity].StageName) && [Opportunity].IsWon,
OR(
NOT ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].StageName),'Closed Won'),
NOT ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].StageName),'Won Awaiting Payment')
)
)
```

---

To say this another way for clarification:

I want the statement to be TRUE if:

```
StageName ISCHANGED & Opportunity.IsWon
BUT NOT IF either of these are TRUE,
PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].StageName),'Closed Won'
PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].StageName),'Won Awaiting Payment'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

AND ( 
ISCHANGED([Opportunity].StageName),
[Opportunity].IsWon,
NOT ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].StageName),'Closed Won'),
NOT ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].StageName),'Won Awaiting Payment')
)

Here these 4 condition need to match : 
1. Stage changed
2. ISwon = True 
3. Prior Val != Closed 
4. Prior Val != Won Awaiting Payment

Comment: Works beautifully - thanks so much. Hugely appreciated :)

Comment: @steve17admin  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Formula as the condition and try the below code, guess should do the work

IF(ISCHANGED([Opportunity].StageName),
    IF(  NOT (ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].StageName),'Closed Won') || ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].StageName),'Won Awaiting Payment') ) ,true, false )
 , False)

Comment: Thanks to you too. The previous answer works but I will also try yours....it works too! Thank you also for your quick and excellent reply - appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you for your response :)